# Jupyter: Line magic function not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've got a persistent error:

```
%%writefile csvmagic.py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def csv(line, cell):
    sio = StringIO(cell)
    return pd.read_csv(sio)

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    """This function is called when the extension is
    loaded. It accepts an IPython InteractiveShell
    instance. We can register the magic with the
    `register_magic_function` method of the shell
    instance."""
    ipython.register_magic_function(csv, 'cell')

Overwriting csvmagic.py



%reload_ext csvmagic
%%csv
col1,col2,col3
0,1,2
3,4,5
7,8,9

UsageError: Line magic function `%%csv` not found.
```

"*Line* magic" does not look quite right to me, but I can't figure it out.

The source is [here](https://ipython-books.github.io/14-creating-an-ipython-extension-with-custom-magic-commands/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Afaik, you must put cell magics at the beginning of a cell. However, `%%csv` is inside of your code block. Make sure that the section starting with `%%csv` is in a cell of its own. Otherwise, what is supposed to be a cell magic will be interpreted as a line magic.